# how do i get rid of the prompt in this c program?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
FILE *f ;
f = popen("passwd mukesh","w");
fprintf(f,"c\n");
fprintf(f,"c\n");
pclose(f);
}
```

is there any way to get rid of the prompt and pass on the password using the program itself

more specifically as a parameter to the `a.out` executable.

**EDIT : or perhaps something like this also doesn't work:**

```
#include <unistd.h>   /* crypt(), etc.          */
#include <pwd.h>      /* getpass(), getpwnam(). */
#include <string.h>   /* strcmp(), etc.         */

void
main()
{
    /* buffers for reading in the user name and the password. */
    char user[21];
    char* password;
    /* storing the encrypted password, and the salt. */
    char* encrypted_password;
    char salt[2];
    /* user's "/etc/passwd" entry. */
    struct passwd* user_info;

    /* prompt the user for a user name. */
    printf("User name: ");
    fflush(stdout); /* flush the prompt to make sure the user sees it. */
    fgets(user, 20, stdin);
    /* fgets() stores also the new-line that the user typed in. so we */
    /* need to locate the new-line character, and truncate it.        */
    if (strchr(user, '\n'))
    (*(strchr(user, '\n'))) = '\0';

    /* prompt the user for their password. the getpass() function  */
    /* prints the given prompt, turns off echo (so the password    */
    /* typed won't be seen on screen), and returns the string that */
    /* the user types.                                             */
    password = getpass("Password: ");

    /* find the user's encrypted password, as stored in "/etc/passwd". */
    user_info = getpwnam(user);
    if (!user_info) {
        printf("login incorrect.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* take the salt as stored in the password field of the user. */
    strncpy(salt, user_info->pw_passwd, 2);

    /* encrypt the given password using the found "salt". */
    encrypted_password = crypt(password, salt);

    /* compare the results of crypt, with the user's stored password field. */
    if (strcmp(user_info->pw_passwd, encrypted_password) != 0) {
        printf("login incorrect.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* authentication succeeded... */
    printf("login successful.\n");
}
```

Comment: `man passwd` and/or `passwd --help`? I highly doubt the new pw can be passwd via cli, as that'd allow the pw to show up in process lists and whatnot. it'd be a major security issue.

Comment: Why is there a `popen`? shouldn't it be a `fopen`?

Comment: @Cygwinnian: `man popen`?

Comment: @Cygwinnian: op is trying to execute the command line `passwd` app. e.g. RUN the app, not just open a file named 'passwd mukesh' for reading.

Comment: `passwd` doesn't accept passwords on the command line, since this is a grave security breach. The command lines of all processes are world-readable, so anyone who has access to the system could potentially see them.

Comment: is there any source code in c/C++ that i can see for passwd implementation so that i can undersatnd its working and try to write my own passwd.i saw somebody had written his own passwd utility in some forum while i was googling....unfortunatly the guy didn't wanted to share the code

Comment: You'd better pass the password as environment variable instead of command line argument. That way it will not be world-readable. Of course when operating from command line, it pays to be careful how you set that env variable, too. But when running from another application, it's easier to stay secure in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with passwd, but you can use **usermod** with the -p flag. From **man usermod**,

```
-p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).

       Note: This option is not recommended because the password 
 (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
```